# My HTML document is not linking to my CSS stylesheet properly

Tags: html, css

I have been copy and pasting HTML and CSS tutorials to try to make this work, right now I have;

page (HTML)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<h1>1This site</h1>
<p>Welcome to the this site</p>
</body>

</html>
```

style.css

```
body {background-image:url(“Background.png”);}
h1 {font-family:Arial, sans-serif;}
```

The when I load the html in safari it still look unformatted.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, use the correct quotation marks around `“Background.png”` - either `'..'` or `".."`. Secondly, have you checked your console - no errors? It's in the correct directory right?

Comment: clear your browser cache.

Comment: I would use fiddler to make sure all of your resources (css and image) are mapped correctly.

Comment: I copied your set up. As null suggested, replacing the quotation marks fixed it.

Comment: The quotations fixed it for me to, thanks!

Comment: Everything seems to be proper.. Only thing you've to worry is whether the name of the directory is spelled correct and check whether your href is pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check to see if you are setting the paths right
if you still have a problem try to use fill path for it :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1/test/style/style.css" />
```

Comment: the path was off by a 's', Now my page.html goes blank when I load it thou.

Comment: are you using wamp or xamp ? load the css directly in your browser see if it loads

Comment: These are stored on my macbook pro, not a server.